# White space issues in two column article

Tags: two-column, white-space

I am using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` and the package `widetext` for long equations. White space is not used consistently through the document leading to a couple of localized issues:

1. After a certain subsection, there is a lot of white before the title of the next subsection.
2. The title of one section appears very close (too little white space) to the text from the previous section.

These issues occur only a couple of times, in other instances spacing works fine. What commands could I use to solve this issues globally or locally?

Comment: I have solved problem 2. The reason was using /newpage before the section (which was not introducing a new page but rather removing white space).

Comment: I suspect problem 1 is caused because paragraphs, titles and equations are 'vertically justified' to avoid empty space at the end of a page, is there any way to avoid this locally?

Comment: May be because you left not chances to this vertical justification in oter places, but without check a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is impossible to say.